# Google Cloud Platform - Viewing downloaded files after wget

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

I am completing this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/getting-started-training-prediction) and am at the part where you download the code for the tutorial.  The request we send to Github is:

```
wget https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/archive/master.zip
```

I understand that this downloads archive to GCP, and I can see the files in the Cloud shell, but is there a way to see the files through the Google Console GUI?  I would like to browse the files I have downloaded to understand their structure better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking on the ***pencil icon*** on the ***top right corner***, the ***Cloud Shell Code editor*** will pop.

Quoting the documentation:

> "The built-in code editor is based on Orion. You can use the code
>   editor to ***browse file directories as well as view and edit files***, with
>   continued access to the Cloud Shell. The code editor is available by
>   default with every Cloud Shell instance."

You can find more info here: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#code_editor

If you prefer to use the command line to view files, you can install and run the tree Unix CLI command [1](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) and run it in Cloud Shell to list contents of directories in a tree-like format.

- install tree => `$ sudo apt-get install tree`
- run it => `$ tree ./ -h --filelimit 4`

`-h` will show human readable size of files/directories

and you can use `--filelimit` to set the maximum number of directories to descent within the list.

Use `$ man tree` to see the available parameters for the command, or check the man online documentation here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree